# How can an engine provide routes to the main app without using the engine's name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

Devise allows an app to use routes methods like `new_user_session_path`

But if I create my own mountable engine that does authentication, I have to use `myengine.new_user_session_path` when calling it in the main app.

How can I use routes urls like Devise does?

Could it be due to using a normal rails engine vs a mountable one?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is now out of the box way to do so. Devise uses special stuff for that. The '[devise_for](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper:devise_for)' method generates all needed routes. Path helpers for that routes (such as 'new_user_session_path') a defined in [Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/UrlHelpers) and included to ActionController::Base.